# How to access a user defined field/column in Outlook VBA

Tags: vba, outlook, ms-office

I am working on creating a macro in Outlook VBA that aims to copy contacts from my default contact-folder to another contact-folder, conditioned by the values of a user-defined field. When refrencing the value of a built in field, the code works as desired. However, the problem arrises when trying to reference the values of a user-defined field. My code seems to be unable to reach the field.

Here, when referencing to the title of the contact ("title" being a built-in field), VBA finds it immediately and there is no problem.

```
Sub copyitem() ' Copy and move all contacts from default folder "Contacts" to "Contacts.1.01

Dim olookitem As Object
Dim olookname As NameSpace
Dim olookfldr As folder
Dim destfolder As folder
Dim olookcontactitem As ContactItem
Dim mycopieditem As ContactItem


Set olookname = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set olookfldr = olookname.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderContacts)
Set destfolder = olookfldr.Folders("Contacts.1.01")


For Each olookitem In olookfldr.items
    
    If olookitem.Class = olContact And olookitem.Title = "Mr." Then
        
        Set olookcontactitem = olookitem
        
                Set mycopieditem = olookitem.Copy
        
        mycopieditem.Move destfolder
        
        
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

However, when trying to reference which team in my office the contact belongs to (Column named "Team"), which is defined in a user-defined field, my macro fails to recognize it. Code following below.

```
Sub copyitem() ' Copy and move all contacts from default folder "Contacts" to "Contacts.1.01

Dim olookitem As Object
Dim olookname As NameSpace
Dim olookfldr As folder
Dim destfolder As folder
Dim olookcontactitem As ContactItem
Dim mycopieditem As ContactItem
Dim Myproperty As Object


Set olookname = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set olookfldr = olookname.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderContacts)
Set destfolder = olookfldr.Folders("Contacts.1.01")
Set Myproperty = olookfldr.UserDefinedProperties.Find("Team")

Set MyP = olookfldr.UserDefinedProperties

' MsgBox (MyP.item(1).Name)
For Each olookitem In olookfldr.items
    
    If olookitem.Class = olContact And MyP.item(9).Name = "Accounting" Then
           
            
        Set olookcontactitem = olookitem
        
                Set mycopieditem = olookitem.Copy
        
        mycopieditem.Move destfolder
        
        
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Why do you need to check a folder's property each time in the loop?

Answer (score 0):

User-defined (and all other) properties can be retrieved using `ContactItem.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty`. The method takes the DASL property name as the parameter; to see the properties and their DASL names, take a look at an item with that property set with [OutlookSpy](https://www.dimastr.com/outspy) (I am its author) - click IMessage button, select the property, see its DASL name.

You can also retrieve a user property using `ContactItem.UserProperties.Item("PropertyName")`, but the custom property must be added as a user property, while `ContactItem.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty` can retrieve any available property.

Comment: Thank you Dmitry. Would you be able to give a quick example code of the propertyaccessor method?

Comment: Sure: `theValue = olookitem.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/string/{00020329-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}/Accounting/0x0000001F")` Keep in mind that if the property does exist on the item, `GetProperty` will raise an exception, which you need to expect, trap, and ignore.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the property value of the user-defined field from the contact item, not folder:

```
Dim userProps as Outlook.UserProperties
Dim userProp as Outlook.UserProperty
For Each olookitem In olookfldr.items
    If olookitem.Class = olContact The  
        Set olookcontactitem = olookitem
        Set userProps = olookcontactitem.UserProperties
        Set userProp = userProps.Find("Team")
        Dim value as String = userProp.Value
        If value = "Accounting" Then
          Set mycopieditem = olookitem.Copy
          mycopieditem.Move destfolder
        End If
    End If
Next
```

Comment: That worked great. Top man! Thank you Eugene.